# How do you keep the title of a post. to NOT show when publishing the post?

Tags: title

There is one post, in fact is the first post I have, and I do not know how to make the post title from not showing. I have tried using various plugins from the WordPress repository and none of them worked. So, how do you keep the title of a post from NOT showing when the post is published?

To view the site: https://whatyaoughtadoisconsider.com

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is to give the post an empty string as title.
This means whenever your title is shown it will not contain anything, and will not output anything, except an empty tag. Furthermore, you can choose not to render that tag at all using an appropriate CSS selector +  `::empty`. For example:

```
.entry-title::empty {
  display:none;
}
```

If you want your post to have a title and only be hidden in a particular place (or places) on your website, you need to provide more context about your request.
In principle, you need to find a CSS selector for that case (or cases) and use it to apply `display:none;` to the title.